# Calculating rolling mean on dataframe column when grouping by IDs in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

**Given df:**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'a':'id1', 'b':10}, {'a':'id2', 'b':20}, 
{'a':'id1', 'b':11}, {'a':'id2', 'b':21},
{'a':'id3', 'b':12}, {'a':'id3', 'b':'NaN'},
{'a':'id1', 'b':0}, {'a':'id2', 'b':23}, 
{'a':'id1', 'b':0}, {'a':'id5', 'b':0}, {'a':'id4', 'b':10}, {'a':'id2', 'b':20}, 
{'a':'id4', 'b':11}, {'a':'id2', 'b':21},
{'a':'id1', 'b':12}, {'a':'id2', 'b':'NaN'},
{'a':'id3', 'b':0}, {'a':'id4', 'b':23}, 
{'a':'id1', 'b':0}, {'a':'id2', 'b':0}])
```

I am calculating rolling means and maximums of previous values in column 'b' for the given 'ids' stored in column 'a'.

The current code I'm using was only shifting correctly given alternating between two id types in column a, so as soon as additional ids where added in real life the approach didn't work correctly:

```
df['rolling_mean_2'] = (df.assign(b=df.b.shift())
               .groupby('a')['b']
               .rolling(window=2, min_periods=2)
               .mean()
               .sort_index(level=1)
               .shift()
               .values)

df['rolling_mean_last'] = (df.assign(b=df.b.shift())
               .groupby('a')['b']
               .rolling(window=1, min_periods=1)
               .mean()
               .sort_index(level=1)
               .shift()
               .values)

df['rolling_max_4'] = (df.assign(b=df.b.shift())
               .groupby('a')['b']
               .rolling(window=4, min_periods=4)
               .max()
               .sort_index(level=1)
               .shift()
               .values)
```

**Outputs the below:**

```
     a  b   rolling_mean_2  rolling_mean_last   rolling_max_4
0   id1 10    NaN            NaN                    NaN
1   id2 20    NaN            NaN                    NaN
2   id1 11    NaN           10.0                    NaN
3   id2 21    NaN           20.0                    NaN
4   id3 12    10.5          11.0                    NaN
5   id3 NaN   NaN           21.0                    NaN
6   id1 0     16.5          12.0                    NaN
7   id2 23    NaN           NaN                     NaN
8   id1 0     5.5           0.0                     NaN
9   id5 0     NaN           23.0                    NaN
10  id4 10    NaN           0.0                     NaN
11  id2 20    NaN           0.0                     NaN
12  id4 11    5.0           10.0                    11.0
13  id2 21    10.0          20.0                    NaN
14  id1 12    10.5          11.0                    11.0
15  id2 NaN   22.0          21.0                    NaN
16  id3 0     11.5          12.0                    12.0
17  id4 23    NaN           NaN                     NaN
18  id1 0     10.0          0.0                     NaN
19  id2 0     22.0          23.0                    NaN
```

**My expected output is:**

```
    a   b   rolling_mean_2  rolling_mean_last   rolling_max_4
0   id1 10  NaN                 NaN                NaN
1   id2 20  NaN                 NaN                NaN
2   id1 11  NaN                 10.0               NaN
3   id2 21  NaN                 20.0               NaN
4   id3 12  NaN                 NaN                NaN
5   id3 NaN NaN                 12.0               NaN
6   id1 0   10.5                11.0               NaN
7   id2 23  20.5                21.0               NaN
8   id1 0   10.75               0.0                NaN
9   id5 0   NaN                 NaN                NaN
10  id4 10  NaN                 NaN                NaN
11  id2 20  22                  21.0               NaN
12  id4 11  5.0                 NaN                NaN
13  id2 21  21.5                23.0               23.0
```

Comment: I've tried running set(df['a']) to see if I can perform .shift() on the set of id's that I'm targeting, but that hasn't worked as set doesn't have a .shift attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using:
    df['rolling_mean_last'] = df.groupby('a')['b'].apply(lambda x: x.rolling(window=1, min_periods=1).mean().shift())

Was able to output expected df.